# Ocultar las tablas hasta que se envie la respuesta

Tags: php, html

tengo un problemilla, realice un pequeño script para rastrear paquetes por Internet.

Funciona adecuadamente, el problema es que antes de que el cliente envie su número de guia las tablas ya se muestran (vacias) y una vez que se pone la guia ya aparecen los datos que jala de la API.

Hay forma de que mientras no se presione el boton enviar y haya respuesta las tablas no se vean?

Quiero que solo aparezcan cuando ya tiene datos que mostrar.

El código del sitio es este:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rastrea tu paquete</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link href="css/public.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  body { background-color: #EFF3F6; padding: 20px; }
  .legend { margin-top: 0 }
  .g-recaptcha { min-height: 78px; }
  .panel-body { padding: 5px; }
  .form-container { padding: 20px; border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; }
    /*********** Theme Designer **********/
.form-container {
}
#form-app {
}
#form-app .form-group {
}
#form-app .form-control {
}
#form-app .form-control:focus {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-primary {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-primary:hover, #form-app .btn.btn-primary:active, #form-app .btn.btn-primary:focus {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-default {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-default:hover, #form-app .btn.btn-default:active, #form-app .btn.btn-default:focus {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-warning {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-warning:hover, #form-app .btn.btn-warning:active, #form-app .btn.btn-warning:focus {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-danger {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-danger:hover, #form-app .btn.btn-danger:active, #form-app .btn.btn-danger:focus {
}
#form-app .btn.btn-info:hover, #form-app .btn.btn-info:active, #form-app .btn.btn-info:focus {
}
#form-app .control-label {
}
#form-app ::placeholder {
}
#form-app h1, #form-app h2, #form-app h3, #form-app h4, #form-app h5, #form-app h6, #form-app .legend {
}
#form-app p {
}
#form-app .help-block {
}
#form-app a {
}
#form-app a:hover {
}
#form-app .steps .step .stage, #form-app .steps .step:before, #form-app .steps .step:after {
}
#form-app .steps .step .stage {
}
#form-app .steps .step:after, #form-app .steps .step:before {
}
#form-app .steps .step.current .stage, #form-app .steps .step.current:after, #form-app .steps .step.current:before {
}
#form-app .steps .step.success .stage, #form-app .steps .step.success:after, #form-app .steps .step.success:before {
}
#form-app .steps .step .title {
}
#form-app .steps .step.current .title {
}
#form-app .steps .step.success .title {
}
.alert {
}
.alert-success {
}
.alert-danger {
}
.alert-info {
}
.alert-warning {
}
.has-error .form-control {
}
.has-error .help-block, .has-error .control-label, .has-error .radio, .has-error .checkbox, .has-error .radio-inline, .has-error .checkbox-inline, .has-error.radio label, .has-error.checkbox label, .has-error.radio-inline label, .has-error.checkbox-inline label {
}
.required .control-label:after, .required-control .control-label:after {
}
#recaptcha, .g-recaptcha {
}
.signature-pad {
}
.signature-pad canvas {
}
input[type=checkbox] {
}
.checkbox-inline {
}
input[type=radio] {
}
.radio-inline {
}
.custom-control .checkbox label::before, .custom-control .inline-control-checkbox label::before {
}
.custom-control .checkbox label::after, .custom-control .inline-control-checkbox label::after {
}
.custom-control .checkbox input:checked+label::before, .custom-control .inline-control-checkbox input:checked+label::before {
}
.custom-control .checkbox input:checked+label::after, .custom-control .inline-control-checkbox input:checked+label::after {
}
.custom-control .radio label::before, .custom-control .inline-control-radio label::before {
}
.custom-control .radio label::after, .custom-control .inline-control-radio label::after {
}
.custom-control .radio input:checked+label::before, .custom-control .inline-control-radio input:checked+label::before {
}
.custom-control .radio input:checked+label::after, .custom-control .inline-control-radio input:checked+label::after {
}
.btn.prev {
}
#form-app .btn.prev:hover, #form-app .btn.prev:active, #form-app .btn.prev:focus {
}
.btn.next {
}
#form-app .btn.next:hover, #form-app .btn.next:active, #form-app .btn.next:focus {
}
.progress {
}
.progress-bar {
}
.table {
}
.well {
}

  </style>
  <script>
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-container">
                            <div id="messages"></div>
                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-app">
<fieldset class="row">

<!-- Heading -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="legend">Rastreo de Paquetes</h3>
</div>


<!-- Select List -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="carrier">Paquetería</label>
        <select id="carrier" name="carrier" data-alias=""  class="form-control" required  >
            <option value="UPS" >UPS</option>
            <option value="Redpack" >Redpack</option>
            <option value="Estafeta" >Estafeta</option>
            <option value="DHL" >DHL</option>
            <option value="99 Minutos" >99 Minutos</option>
            <option value="FedEx" >FedEx</option>
            <option value="iVoy" >iVoy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Number -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="number">Número de guía o ID de Envío</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipment" name="shipment" value="" data-alias="" data-integer-only="true"  class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-action">
        <button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="" style="display:none"><label class="control-label" for="_email">Disculpe, pero deje este campo en blanco</label><input type="text" id="_email" class="form-control" name="_email"></div> </form>
<div id="respuesta"></div>

<?php

include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

$params = array(
  "api_key" => $API_KEY,
  "carrier" => $carrier,
  "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
);
$headers = array(
  "api_key=".$API_KEY
);
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$respuesta = json_decode($response);
//Show the response on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->pickup_date."</td></tr>";

//Show checkpoints data in a table
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Checkpoint</td><td>Fecha</td><td>Código</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Ciudad</td><td>Estado</td><td>País</td><td>Comentarios</td></tr>";
foreach($respuesta->checkpoints as $checkpoint){
  echo "<tr><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->date."</td><td>".$checkpoint->code."</td><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->city."</td><td>".$checkpoint->state."</td><td>".$checkpoint->country."</td><td>".$checkpoint->comments."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>


                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anteriormente lo manejaba con un archivo por separado para que se hiciera la consulta a la API pero me mostraba una pagina en blanco con solo la tabla y se veía muy feo quiero que se vea en la misma pagina que el cliente pone su guía solo por debajo y esto fue lo que se me ocurrió solo que no pensé que se mostraría la tabla en todo momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, solo he hecho una declaración simple para verificar si el POST está configurado y luego se construye la tabla.

Aquí el PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["carrier"])) {


    include_once "key.php";
    $shipment_number = $_POST["shipment"];
    $carrier = $_POST["carrier"];

    $params = array(
        "api_key" => $API_KEY,
        "carrier" => $carrier,
        "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
    );
    $headers = array(
        "api_key=" . $API_KEY
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $respuesta = json_decode($response);
    //Show the response on HTML format with tables
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>" . $respuesta->shipment_status . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>" . $respuesta->event_description . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>" . $respuesta->carrier_tracking_number . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>" . $respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>" . $respuesta->pickup_date . "</td></tr>";

    //Show checkpoints data in a table
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>Checkpoint</td><td>Fecha</td><td>Código</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Ciudad</td><td>Estado</td><td>País</td><td>Comentarios</td></tr>";
    foreach ($respuesta->checkpoints as $checkpoint) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $checkpoint->description . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->date . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->code . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->description . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->city . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->state . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->country . "</td><td>" . $checkpoint->comments . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></td></tr>";

    echo "</table>";

}
?>
```